# Latex Installation issue

Tags: lyx, texstudio

Background to the problem: I am new to Linux and Latex. I had installed Lyx and TeX Studio. My understanding is that some version of Latex through Tex Live was installed. I do not know if it was the full version of TeX Live. A search revealed the following regarding the Tex Live I had.

```
(base) deep@deeplinux:~$ latex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

I installed a full version of TeX Live 2020 (4 GB) today. When I do the same search '''tex --version''' on my terminal I get TeX Live 2017. I don't know what my LyX or TeX Studio is connecting to i.e. TeX Live 2017 or TeX Live 2020.

My goal is to connect my LyX and TeX Studio to the Tex Live 2020 installation so I can use all the packages installed by TeX Live 2020.

I would appreciate some help please. Thanks.

Comment: You should completely remove the old TeX installation via the package manager of Debian. I suppose `sudo apt remove texlive-full`. Then create a path variable into your local `.bashrc` or the global `/etc/profile`: `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`

Comment: That worked. For some reason there was an older version of texlive. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at what is inside the PATH variable, e.g. by `echo $PATH`. If you do not find the Debian TeX Live path there, try `which pdflatex` to find the location. As your Debian TeX is very old I would recommend to delete it via package manager.

In case you find the path of the Debian TeX executables in PATH, change this path (probably in your `.bashrc`) to the location of your TeX Live 2020. I would recommend you to take this approach  but alternatively you may force TeX Studio to work with the executables provided with TeX Live 2020 by setting the executable in the configuration menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks...this also worked as I tried both ways and I learned to look things up in texstudio.

Comment: Please accept the answer then :-)